# Как запретить изменение размера окна C# UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

Я использую технологию UWP(Windows UI) для создания своего приложения, как мне запретить изменение размера окна пользователем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, походу это невозможно. Иначе в документации Microsoft это было бы написано